# Android: Custom annotation the requires calling of a method depending on the set value of the annotated variable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

Something that is similar to `@RequiresPermission("android.permission.INTERNET")` that will ask for permission when a certain annotated method is used.

Can you create a custom annotation that will require the user to call a method after setting a value of the annotated variable?

Example

```
protected abstract var interceptBackPress: Boolean
```

I want to require or warn the consumer (child class) that when `interceptBackPress` is set to `false`, they will need to call a method `requireActivity().onBackPressed()`. While when set to `true` they will be required to override a method from the parent class.

Example method to override

```
    @EmptySuper
    open fun onBackPressed() {
    }
```

Note that both `interceptBackPress` and `onBackPressed()` is define in the parent class.